# Logistic regression overfits even using cross validation in sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, logistic-regression

I am implementing a logistic regression model using sklearn, for a text classification competition on Kaggle.

1. When I use unigram, there are 23,617 features. The best `mean_test_score` Cross validation search (sklearn's `GridSearchCV`) gives me is similar to the score I got from Kaggle, using the best model.
2. There are 1,046,524 features if I use bigram. `GridSearchCV` gives me a better `mean_test_score` compared to unigram, but using this new model I got a much much lower score on Kaggle.

I guess the reason might be overfitting, since I have too many features. I have tried to set the `GridSearchCV` using 5-fold, or even 2-fold, but the scores are still inconsistent.

Does it really indicate my second model is overfitting, even in the validation stage? If so, how can I tune the regularization term for my logistic model using sklearn? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Whoever downvotes, please add your comment. So I can ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using sklearn. You could try looking into using the tuning parameters `max_df`, `min_df`, and `max_features`. Throwing these into a GridSearch may take a long time but you will likely get some interesting results back. I know these features are implemented in the [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), but I am sure they use them elsewhere as well. Essentially the idea is that including too many grams can lead to overfitting, same thing with having too many grams with low or high document frequencies.

Comment: Do you know why the `mean_test_score` is pretty good in cross validation search? Is that because overfitting occurs before enters validation subset?